# gcc linking error: /usr/bin/ld: undefined reference to symbol 'dnrm2_'

Tags: gcc, linker, fortran

I am trying to compile a Fortran program call ShengBTE. It uses a make file whose content is as follows -

```
export FC=gfortran
export FFLAGS=-gfortran -g -O2 -fPIC  -fbounds-check
export CFLAGS=-I/home/user/local/include
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64/ -llapack -lgfortran
```

When I run make from the root folder I get the following error -

```
gfortran -g -O2 -fPIC  -fbounds-check -o ../ShengBTE conductivity.o config.o data.o input.o iterations.o misc.o gruneisen.o phonon_routines.o integrals.o processes.o scaling.o symmetry.o wedgetc.o ShengBTE.o -L/usr/lib64/ -llapack -lgfortran 
/usr/bin/ld: conductivity.o: undefined reference to symbol 'dnrm2_'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'dnrm2_' is defined in DSO /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib64/libblas.so.3: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: [../ShengBTE] Error 1 (ignored)
```

The libblas.so.3 exists under /usr/lib64 and should be available to the linker with the -L option in the make file.

```
ls /usr/lib64/libblas*
lrwxrwxrwx 1     23 Apr 17 15:11 /usr/lib64/libblas.so -> /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1     30 Jun 27  2013 /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3 -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 362704 Mar 20  2013 /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3.4.2*
```

I read somewhere that gcc can be picky about the order in which files are linked. How do I change that through the make file?

Comment: Try -lblas to cause the linker to search that library.

Comment: Added -lblas in the LDFLAGS section of the make file. When I try make now I get a bunch of new errors -



gfortran -g -O2 -fPIC  -fbounds-check -o ../ShengBTE conductivity.o config.o data.o input.o iterations.o misc.o gruneisen.o phonon_routines.o integrals.o processes.o scaling.o symmetry.o wedgetc.o ShengBTE.o -L/usr/lib64/ -lblas -llapack -lgfortran 
ShengBTE.o: In function `MAIN__':
ShengBTE.f90:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `mpi_init_'
ShengBTE.f90:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `mpi_comm_rank_'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: [../ShengBTE] Error 1 (ignored)

Comment: You fixed the previous error. Now you need to link the library for mpi.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @M.S.B. I have linked the library for mpi in the make file using -lmpi which as I understand should look for libmpi.so. The above so file exists on my system as you can see in the following o/p - lrwxrwxrwx 1 44 Apr 20 19:00 /usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/lib64/libmpi.so -> /usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/lib64/libmpi.so.1*  Still I get an error on running make saying ld couldn't find -lmpi. What am I missing?

Comment: Also FYI, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is correctly set.